# Sublime vintage mode (vim) delete, yank, change to regex

Tags: vim, sublimetext

Any way to configure so that the following vim commands which delete, yank or change to regex will function?

```
d/something/
y/something/
c/something/
```

Currently when you press the '/' key it pops up the search toolbar and is no longer within the context of the delete, yank or change command. Is it possible to disable / from opening up the search box and allowing the commands above?

As an example of how the delete command *should* behave in vim:

This line of text:

```
I want something done here
```

When you type:

```
d/something/
```

in command mode with a cursor at the start of line it should delete everything up to the word something and produce this:

```
something done here
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to "disable" the search, but I cannot figure out what it is you've described up there in that box.

Comment: I'll add an example of what those commands do to the post...

Comment: I'm not as sure as ldigas about the possibility of disabling the search bar. But the commands in Vintage mode are only mappings to ST's own feature: I don't think it's able to do what you want.

Comment: This is sublime, where would I try that?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, `d/foo` is still Vi(m)-only.

Sublime Text doesn't work like that: it's a poor substitute for Vim.